# Updating an Openstreetmap PostgreSQL database after the system restore

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osmosis

My Openstreetmap PostgreSQL database takes a long time – about 25 hours by now – for updating via Osmosis after I had made a system restore at the last weekend. Before making the system restore it took just 18-27 minutes for updating my database.

I work with Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) Linux operating system. The Ubuntu system and the Openstreetmap PostgreSQL database are situated on different hard drives. I ought to add that I made the system restore just for a hard drive where the Ubuntu operating system had been. I didn't touch the disk with the Openstreetmap database.

So my questions are as follows. What had I done wrongly and how may I escape such the problem in the future? Can I speed up an updating process if I will take a backup copy of my database? I made that backup copy in October.

Comment: Is this a virtual machine?

Comment: No, Bernhard. Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) is a usual operating system.

Comment: How much RAM do you have available?

Comment: "For recent planets, InMemory takes close to 64GB of RAM. " see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/PostGIS_Setup

Comment: I have 16GB RAM available. And a computer uses just 1.2GB during updating. Size of my database is about 1GB on a hard disk.

Comment: Please, excuse me. I wanted to write: "Size of my database is about 1TB on a hard disk."